# Using variables as classes in the HTML

Tags: html, css, variables, sass

I have a several variables in my SASS file and i want to use them directly in my HTML as class or style.
I know i can use mapping function but, it's pretty tedious. 
is there any other way to achieve it? simple way?

for example:

sass file:

```
$margin-base-vertical:30px 0;
```

html file:

```
<div class="some-container margin-base-vertical">
 some things
</div>
```

Comment: Usually you'd create a new class for this, like: `.margin-base-vertical { margin: $margin-base-vertical;  }`. You can play around with lists and mixins for some kind of automation. Hard to answer with the info given in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not a good idea. You gonna end up with a really unmantainble code if you use classes that describe styles. Each time you want to change your style, you have to change the markup (HTML) and the CSS.

A best practice is to use semantic markup.

This is where sass turns out really powerful, you can use your variables like this way:

```
.some-container {
    margin: $margin-base-vertical;
}
```

EDIT:

The only alternative I can think about for your problem, is to declare a variable, and then use it on your class, after that, you will have the class you need for your markup.

**SASS file**

```
$margin-base-vertical: 30px 0;
.margin-base-vertical { margin: $margin-base-vertical; }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="some-container margin-base-vertical">
 some things
</div>
```

Comment: I hear what you saying but, sometimes you want several classes to play with, in the HTML and not touching your CSS like in my case. i used variables like your suggestion in other places but, im searching to use them in a different way like i asked.

Comment: What I do on those cases its just create a class on sass, and then use it on the markup. CSS and HTML live in parallels universes, there is no way to accomplish what you are asking. But you can declare a variable, use it on your classes and then use it on your markup. See edit I made to my answer.